# How do movies make small places fog up

Tags: production, effects

When somebody is burned and gets put out, you will usually see smoke in small places where you can't get a fog machine in. Or in a Airplane! With the smoking ticket, how do they do that effect?

Comment: Are you sure they can't get a fog machine in? Film and television crews can get pretty ingenious with stuff like that.

Comment: You can pipe fog or smoke through pretty small tubes.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RIBxLm66aMA , https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=APTf1HwzRR4 , etc.

Comment: This is a fair question, even if the answer seems a but obvious to some. The use of dry ice, fog machines, or other practical effects should be recognized within the context of this question.

Answer (score 1):

In the past they probably had to get the fog on it, then film quickly.

My guess on the smoking ticket in the movie Airplane is that they probably had a thin sheet of dry ice inside the prop.

Today, it's probably mostly done with cgi, although some directors still favor physical effects wherever possible, since cgi can get a little boring once you can do anything with it.